# Google+ Sign In Button not functioning Android Studio

Tags: android, scope, google-api-client, google-plus-signin

Hi so I am currently integrating a Google Sign In into my app. Lately this has been my only concern that for some reason Android Studio not recognizing the Plus_Login scope (which is necessary for the app to access basic profile info, etc). My current error is this

```
Error:(40, 17) error: method addScope in class Builder cannot be applied to given types;
required: Scope
found: String
reason: actual argument String cannot be converted to Scope by method invocation conversion
```

and here is my onCreate file where the Error is found

**EDIT 1 - Added import statement and variable declarations**

```
package com.instigate.aggregator06;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;

public class SocialNetworkActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "Social Network Activity";

    /* Request code used to invoke sign in user interactions. */
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

    /* Client used to interact with Google APIs. */
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /* A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents
     * us from starting further intents.
     */
    private boolean mIntentInProgress;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN) // <----- This is where the error is found
                .addScope(Scopes.PLUS_ME)
                .build();

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

I have searched a while to find a solution for this error (seeing as the Plus_Login scope should be functioning) yet have found no solution.

**EDIT 2 - Errors after solving**
I found the answer to this. Apparently instead of:

```
.addScope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN)
.addScope(Scopes.PLUS_ME)
```

we write this

```
.addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
.addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME))
```

which solved my problem.

However, it revealed a new problem:

```
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
```

where logcat points out that there is a NullPointerException at that point.

**EDIT 3 - Solved NullPointerException**
I have solved the NullPointer Exception Problem, however my Google+ Sign In Button will still not function.

here is the overall class (continuation of the code snippet mentioned above)

```
package com.instigate.aggregator06;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;

public class SocialNetworkActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "Social Network Activity";

    /* Request code used to invoke sign in user interactions. */
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

    /* Client used to interact with Google APIs. */
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /* A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents
     * us from starting further intents.
     */
    private boolean mIntentInProgress;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_social_network);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                //.addScope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN)
                //.addScope(Scopes.PLUS_ME)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME))
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
                .build();

        this.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /* Code in case second one doesn't work

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // Could not connect to Google Play Services.  The user needs to select an account,
        // grant permissions or resolve an error in order to sign in. Refer to the javadoc for
        // ConnectionResult to see possible error codes.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);

        if (!mIsResolving && mShouldResolve) {
            if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
                try {
                    connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
                    mIsResolving = true;
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not resolve ConnectionResult.", e);
                    mIsResolving = false;
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            } else {
                // Could not resolve the connection result, show the user an
                // error dialog.
                showErrorDialog(connectionResult);
            }
        }
    }*/

    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!mIntentInProgress && result.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                startIntentSenderForResult(result.getResolution().getIntentSender(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Return to the default
                // state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        // We've resolved any connection errors.  mGoogleApiClient can be used to
        // access Google APIs on behalf of the user.

        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected:" + connectionHint);
        Intent j = new Intent(SocialNetworkActivity.this, AccountPageActivity.class);
        startActivity(j);

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;

            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button) {
            //onSignInClicked();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        // ...
    }

    /* I find this unnecesary

    private void onSignInClicked() {
        // User clicked the sign-in button, so begin the sign-in process and automatically
        // attempt to resolve any errors that occur.
        //mShouldResolve = true;
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        // Show a message to the user that we are signing in.
        //mStatusTextView.setText(R.string.signing_in);
    }*/

    public void backToMainPage(View view) {
        Intent j = new Intent(SocialNetworkActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(j);
    }

}
```

and here is my xml for that class file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.instigate.aggregator06.SelectSNActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/SelectSNActivity"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/backbtn2"
        android:id="@+id/backbtntest"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="43dp"
        android:onClick="backToMainPage"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/selectSocialNetwork"
        android:id="@+id/selectSocialNetworkHeader"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/selectSocialNetworkHeader"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What is your import statement for Scopes

Comment: Missing `setContentView` in activity if not do check the id of the button in xml

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

You are missing `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

Your layout must have

```
 <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Also do check the id of the button in your xml and make sure you reference the same in activity

Comment: When you say reference the same activity, due you mean in the overall xml file? (I also added the xml file in the question for further clarification)

Comment: @RobertMelikyan yes. If its not working you would  need to check the configuration file. json file

Comment: @RobertMelikyan in fact there is sample on github by google for google + signin

Comment: @RobertMelikyan here's the link https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-android

Comment: yes I saw that before (the sample is different from the tutorial). My aim was to create the login on this Activity, and show profile information and contacts on another Activity (which would include the sign out button).

Comment: Google simply puts it all in one activity, making certain objects disappear and others appear

Comment: @RobertMelikyan join the chat @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84373/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-robert-melikyan. can be easily soved via sharedpreferences

Comment: Thanks @Raghunandan I did not know there was a chatroom :)